# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' ' , calcul on dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, sum, series

I would like to add a column that returns the sum of each number for each row in my dataframe.
Here is my code and the error displayed:

```
import pandas as pd

serie = pd.DataFrame({'num':[133,2342,313,4495,4939,19081993,80]})

serie['sum_num'] = sum(map(int,str(serie['num'])))
```

The error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-549615926d0b> in <module>
----> 1 serie['sum_num'] = sum(map(int,str(serie['num'])))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ' '
```

Can you help me ?

Comment: ```serie['sum_num'] = serie['num'].sum()``` should do the trick

Comment: If you just want to some the series, that's ``sum(serie['num'])`` or ``serie['num'].sum()``. But it's unclear to me whether you actually need that – the ``map(int,str(...))`` part seems nonsensical, and "the sum of each number for each row" isn't that clear either. Can you provide the desired output for this example?

Comment: I don't think I made myself clear.
For example for the first column ['num'] = 133 of my dataframe, I would like the column ['sum_num'] = 1 + 3 + 3 = 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
serie["sum_num"] = serie["num"].apply(lambda x: sum(map(int, str(x))))
print(serie)
```

Prints:

```
        num  sum_num
0       133        7
1      2342       11
2       313        7
3      4495       22
4      4939       25
5  19081993       40
6        80        8
```